# lidR installation

Tags: r, lidr

I'm trying to install R and lidR on Debian 11:

Installed r-base-dev v 4.0.4-1 using Synaptics

Starting R in terminal, and:

```
install.packages("lidR", dependencies=TRUE)
```

The install process goes on for ~10 minutes, and ends with:

```
There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘systemfonts’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘s2’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘svglite’ had non-zero exit status
8: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘raster’ had non-zero exit status
9: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
10: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘leafpop’ had non-zero exit status
11: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘satellite’ had non-zero exit status
12: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘lidR’ had non-zero exit status
13: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘leaflet’ had non-zero exit status
14: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘leafem’ had non-zero exit status
15: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘leaflet.extras’ had non-zero exit status
16: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘leafpm’ had non-zero exit status
17: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘mapview’ had non-zero exit status
18: In install.packages("lidR", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘mapedit’ had non-zero exit status
```

Shouldnt this way of installing lidR work?

```
> library(lidR)
Error in library(lidR) : there is no package called ‘lidR’
```

Comment: The error messages show all dependencies failed installation. Maybe the smallest package among these is `units`. Try to install it (for avoiding waiting 10 mins) and then load it. I'm not familiar with Debian, perhaps admin permissions should be conceded when installing libraries

Comment: Not much point showing us the warnings - where's the error messages? What's the first thing that went wrong? Maybe you've not got the packages needed to build packages from source code? Can you edit and show the first error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps I had to take to get it working:

In Synaptics Package manager install: `r-base-dev`

In terminal: `sudo R`, then `install.packages("units")`, didnt work first time so:

synaptics: `libudunits2-dev`

in terminal `sudo R`, then `install.packages("units")`, now it worked

in terminal `sudo R`, then `install.packages("terra")`

synaptics: `libgdal-dev`

in terminal `sudo R`, then `install.packages("terra")`

in terminal `sudo R`, then `install.packages("s2")`

in terminal `sudo R`, then `install.packages("raster")`

in terminal, `sudo R`, then `install.packages("sf")`

in terminal, `sudo R`, then `install.packages("lidR")`

( As a reminder to myself, I then downloaded the latest [R-studio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download) and installed with `sudo apt install /home/bera/Downloads/rstudio-2021.09.1-372-amd64.deb` )

The system dependencies are listed in the [readme](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR#install-lidr-dependencies-on-gnulinux)

Comment: The system dependencies are listed in the [REAME](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR#install-lidr-dependencies-on-gnulinux).